# Can photorec recover .rft files?

Tags: data-recovery, windows-11, photorec

Can photorec recover .rft files? I tried searching for the .rft file and cannot find .rft in the list. It is a text document that has some pictures from a wordpad document. The pictures I just pasted from paint.

I have a file and I saved the file and lost some of the text and pictures in the document.

Would it be recommended to use another file recover program for my uses?

Answer (score 0):

If you made a typo and actually mean the RTF (Rich Text Format) then your in luck. photorec and testdisk do support these
the actual sourcecode lists it under a txt based format. https://git.cgsecurity.org/cgit/testdisk/tree/src/file_txt.c

Unless you mean the IBM DisplayWrite program, which apparently wrote RFT files that also matches your text and images fileformat idea. If the later, we might need to add support for this format.